# Changing one form value based on onChange of another with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, paypal, onchange

I can't seem to get this function to work out. I'm trying to change the "business" input value of my form based on an amount selected in the "amount" dropdown. What am I missing!!! I've been trying this for an hour.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function chPy()
  {
  var businessvar = "paypals@ramatico.com";
  if (document.forms['5'].amount.value > 11){
  businessvar = "paypall@ramatico.com"
  }
  document.forms['5'].business.value = businessvar;
  }
  </script>

  <form name="5">
  <select name="amount" OnChange="chPy()">
      <option value="na">Select</option>
      <option value="1.00">$1</option>
      <option value="5.00">$5</option>
      <option value="10.00">$10</option>
      <option value="15.00">$15</option>
      <option value="20.00">$20</option>
      <option value="25.00">$25</option>
  </select> 
  <input name="business" type="text" value="">
  </form>
```

Ok. The next step. I have about 100 of these forms on a page. Instead of creating one for each form, I'd like to have one script that changes based on which form is being changed with "onChange". Each of the forms on the page have values of the same name (but not ID) (they are for paypal). I think it will be ok if I can change the"formname" in the following: "document.forms['formname']" based on a variable populated by something like chPy("formname") etc..... I can't seem to get that to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the form reference would take care of both of your items.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function chPy(oSelect)
  {
  var businessvar = "paypals@ramatico.com";
  if (oSelect.form.amount.value > 11){
  businessvar = "paypall@ramatico.com"
  }
  oSelect.form.business.value = businessvar;
  }
  </script>

  <form name="5">
  <select name="amount" OnChange="chPy(this)">
      <option value="na">Select</option>
      <option value="1.00">$1</option>
      <option value="5.00">$5</option>
      <option value="10.00">$10</option>
      <option value="15.00">$15</option>
      <option value="20.00">$20</option>
      <option value="25.00">$25</option>
  </select> 
  <input name="business" type="text" value="">
  </form>
```

Comment: I like your answer better than mine :)

Comment: thank you very much. I'm new to javascript and I can always get very close but have to come here to make it work. Thanks to you and everyone else for your help!

Comment: what is oSelect? Can I change that to anything? Why is one letter capitalized....? Thanks for helping me learn this!

Comment: That is just a parameter name. You can call it anything you want. Make sure to change the name everywhere. It represent the element that triggered the event (as being passed as this), in this case the select named as amount.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are using a number as form name.

Add some letters to the name and it will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function chPy()
  {
  var businessvar = "paypals@XYZ.com";
  if (document.forms['form5'].amount.value > 11){
  businessvar = "paypall@XYZ.com"
  }
  document.forms['form5'].business.value = businessvar;
  }
  </script>

  <form name="form5">
  <select name="amount" OnChange="chPy()">
      <option value="na">Select</option>
      <option value="1.00">$1</option>
      <option value="5.00">$5</option>
      <option value="10.00">$10</option>
      <option value="15.00">$15</option>
      <option value="20.00">$20</option>
      <option value="25.00">$25</option>
  </select> 
  <input name="business" type="text" value="">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form name="form5">
    <select name="amount">
        <option value="na">Select</option>
        <option value="1.00">$1</option>
        <option value="5.00">$5</option>
        <option value="10.00">$10</option>
        <option value="15.00">$15</option>
        <option value="20.00">$20</option>
        <option value="25.00">$25</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="text" name="business">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var form5 = document.forms['form5'];

form5.amount.onchange = function() {
    form5.business.value =
        (this.value > 11 ? 'paypall' : 'paypals') + '@ramatico.com';
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Fx7zh/

---

For multiple forms, you can use this JavaScript code:

```
for (var i = 0, l = document.forms.length; i < l; i++) {
    document.forms[i].amount.onchange = function(i) {
        this.form.business.value =
            (this.value > 11 ? 'paypall' : 'paypals') + '@ramatico.com';
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Fx7zh/2/

Comment: hey I tried implementing this into my script... it will select the correct value first, but won't change it if the selection is change. Thanks

Comment: my bad I actually only input part of it. Here's what I'm going with... I tried entering aspects of yours into this and couldn't get it to work hah! 
`<script type="text/javascript">
  function combAction1(frm)
  {
      var formperson = frm.formperson.value;
      var formaction = frm.formaction.value;
      frm.item_name.value = formperson + ", " + formaction;
  }
  function chPy(oSelect)
  {
  var businessvar = "paypals@ramatico.com";
  if (oSelect.form.amount.value > 11){
  businessvar = "paypall@ramatico.com"
  }
  oSelect.form.business.value = businessvar;
  }
</script>`

Comment: @Andypandy That code doesn't have anything to do with my code. What do you mean?